# Issue with UDP message reception in QT

Tags: c++, qt, udp

I want to receive UDP messages using QT. The code I use (see bellow) works well, but the problem is that it only works for one message: after receiving one message, the code still running, but it seems that it doesn't receive anything anymore.

Indeed, after the first message received, the console display *qDebug() << "in !";*, meaning that it enters into the function, but never received other UDP messages.

I already check, I sure the message is well sent by the UDP server. So the problem must come from here. Any suggestions?

Launching UDP when the class is created:

```
App::App(QWidget *parent)
   : QMainWindow(parent), imageLabel(new QLabel)
   , scrollArea(new QScrollArea)
{
    .....
    StartUDP();
    ....
}
```

The UDP initialization:

```
void App::StartUDP()
{
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    bool result =  socket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 17);
    qDebug() << result;
    if(result)
    {
        qDebug() << "PASS";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "FAIL";
    }
    readyRead();
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

The function that what for UDP signal:

```
void App::readyRead()
{
    qDebug() << "in !";
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 port;
    while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(),datagram.size(),&sender,&port);
        qDebug() <<"Message From :: " << sender.toString();
        qDebug() <<"Port From :: "<< port;
        qDebug() <<"Message :: " << datagram;
        file_name = datagram;
        m_SystemTrayIcon->showMessage(tr("Message"), tr("Nouveau fichier détecté"));
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of Qt you use?  5th line is riddled with intermittent bugs related to udp socket.. in some cases it were refactoring problems, in other - developer didn't actually knew how socket is\can be used in real life. `hasPendingDatagrams` got bugs in some. THe call to `readyRead` already means there is a datagram ready

Comment: I use Qt 5.12.2 and Qt creator 4.15.1. Yes I agree with you, it seems to detect the datagram but impossible to read it.

Comment: I don't think you receive any message at all - the first output of qDebug() comes from your own call to readyRead(); before you connect the signal. Use another port and make sure the firewall does not block it.

Comment: Well I did receive a message actually, but only the first one. The qDebug dislay it well. The problem comes with the next messages that are not displayed (and so not received ?)